# Where can I rent a decent mountain bike in Zürich?

Tags: bicycles, rental, zurich

I am going for a 4 day trip in Zürich and I would like to bike quite a lot. Though biking is quite advertised, I failed to find a decent bike rental shop in the city. Would highly appreciate some tips!

Comment: Not sure what is your standard of decent and where you will be biking, and maybe you've already considered the site, but rentabike.ch generally has bikes in good conditions for rental.

Comment: @zhantongz I've checked that one, but for Zurich they only provide a very basic mountain bike (not all models listed under "bicycles").

Comment: rental shops in a city will rent bikes suitable for city use. If you want real "mountain" bikes you should look at rental shops in mountain resorts.

Comment: I'd guess the answer is nowhere. Haven't seen any bike shops rent pro bikes anywhere.

Comment: @KristvanBesien well, there are a number of hills and trails in and around Zürich, so I would expect _someone_ to actually rent bikes for such terrains.

Comment: You could see if any local bike stores offer *demo* bikes.
Strictly speaking you are supposed to be considering buying, but its often not hard to fake sufficient interest.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your requirements are (and as others already mentioned the "better" models are probably mainly available in mountain resorts), but there are at least some shops in Zurich where you can rent mountain bikes (sites in German only)

- [Velofix](https://www.velofix.ch/vermietung) has two models at least
- [Velo Atelier](https://www.veloatelier.ch/aktuell/testen-mieten) offers both street and mountain bikes

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Spinlister](https://www.spinlister.com/) has a few listings, though I'm not sure if any are exactly what you're looking for or how far out of town you'd be willing to travel to do the pickup.