# Where can I rent a decent mountain bike in Zürich?

Tags: switzerland, bicycles, rental, zurich

I am going for a 4 day trip in Zürich and I would like to bike quite a lot. Though biking is quite advertised, I failed to find a decent bike rental shop in the city. Would highly appreciate some tips!

Comment: migrating to travel.se - this is all about a location and very little to do with bicycles.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I rent a decent mountain bike in Zürich?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158659/where-can-i-rent-a-decent-mountain-bike-in-z%c3%bcrich)

Comment: @Justas That link points to the a different version of the same question by the same OP.  I'm guessing he cross posted on Travel and Bicycles and the Bicycles question was punted back here and now you're pointing the original Travel question as being a solution to the original Bicycle question.  Which is silly . unless of course I am missing the /s for sarcasm tag - which is possible

Comment: @PeterM: I think it's just an attempt to close the now-duplicate copy.  The "Does this answer your question" verbiage is added automatically and doesn't really make sense here.